# How to copy code and paste in Rich Text Format with syntax highlighting?

Tags: xhtml, syntax

I want to ability to select code from my program such as dreamweaver or visual studio and then paste the code into a word file or my favourite work processor and have the syntax highlighted as well.

Is there a website that can provide this service with the ability to highlight syntax from various languages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio should already be doing this for you. At least, it does for me with Visual Studio 2005 and Word 2007.

Right here, StackOverflow has syntax highlighting support for multiple languages, but the syntax highlighting doesn't seem to survive a trip through my clipboard from FireFox 3.5 to Word 2007.